# When forecasting something like cancellations for subscription, should I use time series data or a unique rows for each customer

Tags: forecasting

I have a company where a customer can sign up for a subscription for 1 year, quarterly, or monthly. A customer can also cancel at any time. I want to run some forecasting models to predict cancellations by month. Some of the features we have is usage, month of cancel, billing cycle, customer value, and others.

1. What would be some of the best models to run here?
2. Should I use a data set that includes every customer for every billing cycle? Meaning if a customer is on a monthly plan, they would show up in the data every single month untill they cancel? Or should I just use a unique row for each customer and say something like "cancelled 0/1" and "date cancelled".
3. Is there anything I should look out for specifically?

Apologies for the simple questions, I am just starting this out.

Thank you.

I have both data types ready to go, a unique list of customer as well as the time series list with unique ID. I've searched StackOverflow for the answer to which one to use and which model's and havn't had much luck (makes sense, seeing as I'm new here). So hopefully this is an easy theory question to answer.